# Show that $S$ has zero content

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f>0$ bounded from $\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a bounded $S\subset \mathbb{R^2}$. if $\iint_S f \,dA=0$ then show that S has zero content.
I know that for any integrable function $f$ on a S which has zero content this integral is zero. But I couldn't show this.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Assuming $f$ is integrable on $S$, if $S$ does not have zero content, what can you say about $\iint_S f\,dA$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Intuitively I can find a rectangle for all partitions of P in S such that all values of f are positive hence integral is positive but I could not show that. or Am I wrong?